# ProFTPd, MySQL, virtual users and permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions, ftp, proftpd

I want to control my ProFTPd authentication by a MySQL database. Users will be able to change the username and password of their FTP account(s) in a PHP web application. This provokes a following problem: The users set in the database usertable do not match the system users. So I am not able to change the directory permissions in my filesystem and ProFTPd logs the error:

> username chdir("/var/www/vhosts/sites/username"): Permission denied

But how could I give these FTP users access to these folders? If I set up a user called `www-data` it works fine but the usernames will not be defined in `/etc/passwd`.

The second thing I want to manage is the restriction of this only directory, in this case `/var/www/vhosts/sites/username`. The user mustn't have access to other directories if they are not in the home directory above.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use MySQL for authentication, yet you still want to set permissions on directories as if they were system users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to give your proftpd virtual users ownership of their files and directories just like you would a real user. You can do this with [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown). As the users aren't system users you will have to use the numeric UID:GID e.g. if username is UID 10001 and GID 1111 (from the mysql database) then

```
chown  10001:1111 /var/www/vhosts/sites/username
chown  -R 10001:1111 /var/www/vhosts/sites/username
```

should give username control over their own files. Ensure that www-data user has suitable read only access to the file & directories e.g. give world r-x to directories and r-- to files.

If you set the

```
DefaultRoot  ~
```

directive then the users will be confined within their own directory tree.